Why is the GenAI ban no longer pinned in the right-hand sidebar?
Why was the link to the policy banning AI-generated content1 removed from the right-hand sidebar? It's not like the problem has abated.
The link was there as late as last week, but now it's gone.
1 It may have been the meta post announcing the policy.

@cottontail Actually I'm not sure which one the pinned message used to link to. I guess the meta post actually; thanks for prodding.

Also, Ryan M left this comment. Might be a reason why feature tag wasn't returned, or at least why they don't hurry to do so.

The help center link was never pinned in the sidebar, so its really the Meta post you're talking about (it was featured).

Aaaaaand it's back on the "Featured" list: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/421831/67

Thanks for noticing! Post is featured again.

If you are talking about the meta post, then it was removed from the Featured posts because it lost its [featured] tag. According to this post, the featured tag expires on the first Saturday after 30 days. If we look at its revision history, the tag was last added on May 1. Since the first Saturday after 30 days from May 1 was on June 1, it was indeed removed by the Community bot then. I suppose a moderator will come in and add it back soon.

It's gone again now, but maybe we don't need to push further for this.
